# mvc httppost href parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-views, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm currently working in ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF 4.0.
I have an unordered list with listitems. Each listitem contains a name and address and is clickable. Now I want to make it so that, when I click the listitem, I go to a new View. This view is called UitgebreidPersoonScherm and is in thesame controller RelatieZoekenController.

Here's the code I currently have:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UitgebreidPersoonScherm(int psnID)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "UitgebreidPersoonScherm";

    return View("UitgebreidPersoonScherm");
}
```

View:

```
    @model MobileApp.Models.ZoekModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = " Resultaten";
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UitgebreidPersoonScherm", "RelatieZoeken", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "resultForm" }))
    { <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-theme="g">
        @foreach (var adres in Model.AdresList)
        {            
            <li>
            <a href='@Html.Action("UitgebreidPersoonScherm", "RelatieZoeken")'><b>@adres.Naam </b>
                <br />@adres.Adres
            </a></li>
        }
        </ul>

}
```

Now I wouldn't have a clue on how this is possible. I tried to make it with an actionlink, but it wouldn't show my data. If I remove the httppost I can get it to work, but without parameters. Currently it also doesn't give any parameters.

If you need any extra information, just ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

but since you simply return the link, I advise you to substitute it somehow that way:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("UitgebreidPersoonScherm", "RelatieZoeken", new { psnID = adres.Id })'>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to remove the httppost, but it works like this. Thanks again for the help.